I found error FirebaseError: No document to update: projects/local-eats-discovery/databases/(default)/documents/userChats/pmTVrOVTm1fVLn7WODarHl2WKir2
I am building a chat application with react and firebae following a youtube channel, but I get:

FirebaseError: No document to update: projects/local-eats-discovery/databases/(default)/documents/userChats/pmTVrOVTm1fVLn7WODarHl2WKir2.

I don't understand in which part i made a mistake. Please help me to solve this problem.
import { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';


import { db } from '../../Firebase/firebase.config';
import { collection, doc, getDoc, getDocs, query, serverTimestamp, setDoc, updateDoc, where } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { AuthContext } from '../../providers/AuthProviders/AuthProviders';

const SearchUser = () => {
    const [userName, setUserName] = useState('');
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
    const [err, setErr] = useState(false);
    const [loding,setLoding] = useState(false)
    const { user: currentUser} = useContext(AuthContext);
    console.log(currentUser?.uid);

   useEffect(() => {
    if (!currentUser) {
        setLoding(true)
    }
    setLoding(false)
   },[currentUser])
   
    const handelSearch = async () => { 
        const q = query(collection(db, 'users'), where('displayName', '==', userName));

        try {
            const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
            querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                setUser(doc.data());
            });
        } catch (err) { 
            setErr(true);
        }
    }
   
    const handelKey = (e) => { 
        e.code === 'Enter' && handelSearch();
    }


    const handelSelect = async () => {
        // here chacking the group chats in the firebase is exist or not , if not then creat

        { 
            loding && <span> loading...</span>
        }

        const combinedId = currentUser.uid > user.uid ? currentUser.uid + user.uid : user.uid + currentUser.uid;
        
        try {
            const res = await getDoc(doc(db, 'chats', combinedId));
            if (!res.exists()) {
                // create chat in chats collection 
                await setDoc(doc(db, 'chats', combinedId), { message: [] });
            }
        
            // Update userChats documents
            await updateDoc(doc(db, 'userChats', currentUser.uid), {
                [combinedId + '.userInfo']: {
                    uid: user.uid,
                    displayName: user.displayName,
                    photoURL: user.photoURL
                },
                [combinedId + '.date']: serverTimestamp()
            });
        
            await updateDoc(doc(db, 'userChats', user.uid), {
                [combinedId + '.userInfo']: {
                    uid: currentUser.uid,
                    displayName: currentUser.displayName,
                    photoURL: currentUser.photoURL
                },
                [combinedId + '.date']: serverTimestamp()
            });
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }
    return (
        <div className="py-3 px-2">
            <div className="w-full flex justify-start items-start gap-3">
                <input 
                    type="text" 
                    className="border-gray-300 border-2 w-full px-3 py-2 rounded-md" 
                    onKeyDown={handelKey} 
                    onChange={e => setUserName(e.target.value)}
                />
            </div>

            {err && <span>User not found</span>}
            {user && 
                <div className='flex justify-start items-start gap-3 p-5 drop-shadow-md bg-gray-100 mt-4' onClick={handelSelect}>
                    <div><img src={user?.photoURL} alt="" className='w-20'/></div>
                    <div>
                        <h4 className='text-2xs font-bold'>{user?.displayName}</h4>
                        <p className='text-sm text-gray-500'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea harum veniam aspernatur voluptatem ex non ....</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    );
};

export default SearchUser;






I want to mention that my current user data came little bit late.i console the currentUser, initial render it gives undefind then after few second it gives current user data.

You can only use updateDoc when the document already exists, and from the error message that doesn't seem to be the case for you.
A simple alternative is to use setDoc with merge: true as shown in the second code snippet of the documentation on setting a document. Applied to your code that'd be:
await setDoc(doc(db, 'userChats', currentUser.uid), {
    [combinedId + '.userInfo']: {
        uid: user.uid,
        displayName: user.displayName,
        photoURL: user.photoURL
    },
    [combinedId + '.date']: serverTimestamp()
}, { merge: true });

await setDoc(doc(db, 'userChats', user.uid), {
    [combinedId + '.userInfo']: {
        uid: currentUser.uid,
        displayName: currentUser.displayName,
        photoURL: currentUser.photoURL
    },
    [combinedId + '.date']: serverTimestamp()
}, { merge: true });


Unrelated, you can speed things up a bit by letting the two writes run in parallel and using a single await with Promise.all:
await Promise.all([
  setDoc(doc(db, 'userChats', currentUser.uid), {
    [combinedId + '.userInfo']: {
        uid: user.uid,
        displayName: user.displayName,
        photoURL: user.photoURL
    },
    [combinedId + '.date']: serverTimestamp()
  }, { merge: true }),
  setDoc(doc(db, 'userChats', user.uid), {
    [combinedId + '.userInfo']: {
        uid: currentUser.uid,
        displayName: currentUser.displayName,
        photoURL: currentUser.photoURL
    },
    [combinedId + '.date']: serverTimestamp()
  }, { merge: true })
]);

